# Create custom animation like transitionWithView block

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I am using `transitionWithView` animation block to animate view. This block is called when user swipe the view in left or right direction. It works fine. But I want to create my own custom animation like view gets changed from left to right direction. I don't know how to achieve this. I am using `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp` for right to left swipe
and `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown` for left to right swipe in `UIViewAnimationOptions`.

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view duration:0.6 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp animations:^{
        setDataInLayout();
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [scrollViewContent setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
        [self.delegate updatePaginationCounter:_currentStoneIndex];
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement this animation by yourself. I would use UIView animation API like:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.6, animations: {
    // apply 2D transformation to the view, or use any other animatable property
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(fullRotation)
} completion: {finished in
        // you completion block    
})
```

Here is the [list](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html) of UIView's animatable properties. For more complex animations you can use the keyframe-based animation:

```
UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(duration, delay: delay, options: options, animations: {
// add your keyframe animations here

UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0, relativeDuration: 1/2, animations: {
    self.view.transform = ...
})
UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(1/3, relativeDuration: 1/2, animations: {
    self.view.transform = ...
})

}, completion: {finished in
    // completion block
})
}
```